# Recover the first revision of a comment in the inbox

Tags: feature-request, comment, inbox

When someone addresses you in a comment, you'll get notified via your inbox with the first $x\le100$(?) letters of the comment.

When you read the comment on the page, it could have been that the comment was edited, so you can't read the original comment. Is it possible to expand the comment  in the inbox?